# image with in a div is not scaling for landscape orientation in Android

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I have an issue with image scaling..I'm building a mobile website where there is a banner image. I've enclosed this img within a div. Issue is that the image scales fine in iphone as we change the orientation from portrait to landscape..BUT not in Android. I tried media queries..didn't seem to work..Any insight on fixing the issues?
[my page](http://move.clanteam.com/scaling-image.html)

Here is the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/D2jhV/)

Comment: specifying width=100% and height=auto fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a class with width: 100% (not inline) and deliver my banners (and every image for that matter) through Sencha. It will scale every image based on the mobile client in landscape format, the class is used for re-scaling to portrait.

http://docs.sencha.com/io/src/